# How can I get a token in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

The web extension has 2 windows:

1. popup is a window that opens when you click on it
2. content is code that is roughly embedded in the site and displayed on the sites that I specify
   It is necessary that this content does the same thing as popup, that is, it opens the form and you can add posts from there.
   When I started doing it, I thought that in this content, you need to fasten the same authorization as in popup, but when I make it up, an error came out that I already had and that I fixed, but here it was not fixed by that method
   Then I thought that you can not add this authorization and synchronize with the extension, that if the user is not authorized, he was sent to log in to the extension. I started doing this and tried to send requests from content to popup in order to get a token + authentication status from there. But there was a problem that when the pop-up is closed, it disables all scripts and does not apply to it. Then I did it differently, when I entered the pop-up, I saved the token and status in chrome.storage and in the js content, when I clicked on the icon, I checked the values in storage and showed what was needed depending on the status. But there was a problem that the token is not always valid and if after a certain amount of time to send a post, then I will just get an expired token error. Here's the problem that I can't figure out yet how to check and send a new token to the content

I've tried it, but it works poorly

```
content.tsx
  const checkAuth = async () => {
    const auth = await chrome.storage.local.get()
    setIsAuth(auth.isSignedIn)
    setToken(auth.token)
  }
popup.tsx
  useEffect(() => {
    getToken().then((token) => {
      chrome.storage.local.set({ token })
    })
    chrome.storage.local.set({ isSignedIn })
  }, [isSignedIn, getToken])
```

I used clerk auth

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
let accessed_token=localStorage.getItem('token');
```

Comment: I make web-extension
The problem is that when popup is closed, I can't access it, and it has the getToken() method in it.
In popup, I save the token in storage, but then I can't update it for content

Comment: so your issue is you are not able to update the token am i right?